# Prove that $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {n^2 x^2 +1} $ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, real-numbers

How do I prove that $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {n^2 x^2 +1} $ is convergent for every x in real numbers except for $x=0$?

I tried using the ratio test, but it doesn't seem to be conclusive.

Comment: See carefully the example! I think there is a mistake, because the left part of what is given is a series and the right one is a sequence.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I typed it very fast. But it is fixed now. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to know whether $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2x^2 + 1}$ converges.

Two cases:

1. $|x| \geq 1$. In this case, we have $$\frac{1}{n^2x^2 + 1} \leq \frac{1}{n^2 + 1} \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$$
   and $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges.
2. $0<|x| < 1$. In this case, we have
   $$
   \frac{1}{n^2 x^2 + 1} \leq \frac{1}{n^2x^2 + x^2} = \frac{1}{x^2}\frac{1}{n^2 + 1} \leq \frac{1}{x^2}\cdot\frac{1}{n^2}
   $$
   and $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty\frac{1}{x^2}\cdot\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{1}{x^2}\sum_{n = 1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges.

Therefore, the sum $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2x^2 + 1}$ converges as long as $x \neq 0$.

Comment: A little simpler $\frac{1}{n^2x^2+1}\leq \frac{1}{n^2x^2}$. Then you can factor out the $\frac{1}{x^2}$ and use that $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the limit comparison test.

Use $\displaystyle b_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$

Let $\displaystyle a_n = \frac{1}{n^2x^2 + 1}$

$\displaystyle \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \frac{n^2}{n^2x^2 + 1}$

$x$ is a constant $x \ne 0$

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \frac{1}{x^2}$

Provided $x \ne 0, x^2 > 0, \frac{1}{x^2} > 0$ we find that since $\displaystyle \zeta(2) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges to $\displaystyle \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ we find that $\sum a_n$ converges as well. (By Limit Comparison Test)